# sketchy email from apple/itunes

Tags: macos

i recently just upgraded to osx lion(july 30 here). Today I just received a receipt from itunes of my purchase with the receipt date as 01/08/11.

I have read about recurring charges from apple about this but not for credit card(i think the problem was paypal). I immediately double checked my account and sure enough there was only 1 purchase.

Im still paranoid though. I am in  the philippines and I wouldn't want to call their US number(maybe only as a last resort). Was this just a matter of the receipt email being a week late? or is it a real double charge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple delays charging of cards for purchases on the App Store/iTunes, and hence email confirmations. They do this so they don't need to charge your card multiple times if you happen to buy a bunch of stuff close to each other, saves them from having to pay some processing fees.

I bought Lion on July 20th and didn't see an email confirmation until the 25th, and that confirmation listed the receipt date as July 22nd.

Comment: i would like to believe this although i am still ab it skeptic. do you have a reliable link/source/whatnot to back this claim? if so please post so i can accept this :)

Comment: I can also say that the delay is easily a week long - even if they didn't have a big snafu - I wouldn't doubt they audited each one by hand if there was a loop charging someone more than once.

Answer (score 2):

I can't confirm that it's not a phishing attempted, but I upgraded to Lion two days ago (the 8th) and I still haven't received an email confirming my purchase, which is usually the case when I do purchase from the AppStore. Any confirmation emails have always been a few days post-purchase for me, and I've never been double charged (I was also worried the first couple times and check my bank accounts repeatedly), so from my experience you should fine unless you do get a second purchase email as Paul pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Did you receive one receipt e-mail, or two? If you only received one, and you have only been charged once, then I would be very tempted to not worry about it. Just keep an eye on your card statements to ensure that you don't end up getting double billed.

If you received two receipt e-mails, then I would call Apple.

Although I cannot confirm a one week delay, I can certainly confirm a delay of several days, and I could easily believe that there store was very busy during the Lion launch, leading to additional delays in the billing, and receipting.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, It could be a phishing attempt - there are no "recurring charges" on the store - you get billed for the purchase when you make it. I suppose some in app purchases are subscription based, but certainly not Lion.

If you are at all in doubt, forward it to reportphishing@apple.com and use their web site to ask for billing help directly. You'll likely have your mind at ease and can junk that message.

http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/

Click **iTunes Store Account and Billing**, then *Billing Inquiries* and shoot them an email for free.

[image]

Comment: I think the questioner was referring to [this](http://www.macrumors.com/2011/07/27/apple-charges-customer-122-times-for-lion/) story of Apple charging someone 122 times for Lion. There were a few other reports of customers getting charged multiple times. Apple started refunding those customers a few days ago.

Comment: yeah i think that was the one. it did look like an official email as it had the correct transaction id, it just seemed weird i was getting the receipt a week after i purchased it.